# Cartodb user analytics

Tags: carto

I love CartoDb but have a significant issue with the level of analytics CartoDb provide. Does anyone know of a way to capture user hits on a map at all within CartoDb?

Comment: It isn't really what CartoDB is about. Why can't you use a 3rd party analytics library?

Comment: Thanks John. We tend to use very fast dissemination of emergency data via social media so have not pushed users to a website, just the initial map.  We might have to do a little bit more but I was hoping not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapviews of each map that you create in CartoDB are available in the Maps dashboard as well as in the map public page. (See images below).

CartoDB does not provide any other metric besides map views at the moment. If you are interested in detailed information such as unique user hits or more info about your audience, you would have to handle it with an analytics library in the site in which you embed your CartoDB map, as @John Barça explains in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want map specific analytics you should check out [maptiks](http://www.sparkgeo.com/projects/maptiks). It won't give you insight in to maps served by CartoDB, but if you put maps on other sites and use leaflet then it should work great.